# removing whitespace from left start of string without any methods

Tags: javascript

I need to remove all whitespace that is the left end of the string,
I'm not sure how to approach this. I want to try it without using any methods. any ideas?

```
let removeWhiteSpace = function(str) {
  let newString;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] != " " || str[i] != "\t") {
      newString += str[i];
    }
  }
  return newString;
};
```

function("\t value ") // returns "value "

Comment: What are you expecting as an output instead of `value `? Do you want it to keep the `\t`?

Comment: i do not want to keep the \t, \t  is a form of whitespace, thats why i added it in the if statement

Comment: You should also initialize `newString` to an empty string `let newString = '';`

Answer (score 1):

Your version is not performant. Once you get char, you should break. If still ok, please second solution.

```js
const trimLeft = (word = "") => {
  let str = "",
    index = 0,
    len = word.length;
  for (; index < len; index++) {
    const char = word[index];
    if (char !== " " && char !== "\t") {
      str += char;
      break;
    }
  }
  index++;
  for (; index < len; index++) {
    str += word[index];
  }
  return str;
};
console.log(trimLeft(" \t  test asa "));
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet

```
const string = "    te s  t  ";
let nonSpaceChars = [];
for (const char of string)
  if (char != " ")
    nonSpaceChars.push(char);

const result = nonSpaceChars.join('');
console.log(result);
```